# Calling placement new using base class

Tags: c++, new-operator, c++17

I have doubts about placement `new`. I would like to call Base Class constructor in class Derived method. The code should make this more clear.

### Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>
#include <optional>


double calculate_z(int x) {
    return 2 * x;   
}

struct Base {
    int x;
    double z;

    Base(): x(0), z(0) {}
    Base(int value): x(value), z( calculate_z(x)) {}
};

class Derived: public Base {
public:
    //is this enought to make it safe? 
    static_assert( std::is_trivially_copyable<Base>::value, "Object using new in placement constructor has to be trivial!");
    std::optional<bool> force; 

    void load(int x)
    {
        new(this) Base(x); //can I call it safty? will this couse any trouble with force member? 
        // Do I need to call destructor manualy or delate? (probalby no)
        force = std::make_optional(false);
    }
};

int main()
{
    Derived a;
    a.load(5);
}
```

[Link do online compiler](https://wandbox.org/permlink/r4YWrqTgJIjxfstP)

### Reason

Example looks point less. But instead of Base in that class is `T`. Derivative is `template`. I need to call this constructor because I read data from JSON. And I use serialization library that required existing that object already. Not inherit from Base is a problem (because I could use Base as a member). So why I need call constructor? Because T comes from other library and not calling constructor make my app working improper.

**So questions:**

1. Is my program safe?
2. if 1 is yes, Is one traits enough to replace Base with template?
3. if no, how I can make it safe?

### Base as a member

I can't make Base as a member because I serialize this using http://uscilab.github.io/cereal/serialization_functions.html

Comment: First cast `this` to a `Base*` and then to `void*` to make sure the address you pass to placement new is the correct one. Then it will be legal, albeit questionable (and likely brittle). Personally I'd just do something like `static_cast<Base&>(*this) = Base{x};`. I'm not aware of a compiler that won't optimize it properly.

Comment: is there any reason you can't have a protected `setx` method, called in your `Base(int)` constructor and in `load()`

Comment: @UKMonkey `Base` is not my part of code. It's from 3part library.

Comment: I don't see why you need to inherit from `Base` here. Where are you using `Derived` as a `Base`, that you can't just use a member `Base`?

Comment: @Caleth it's because of load function. That is from here this [lib](http://uscilab.github.io/cereal/serialization_functions.html) If I make it member this Archive would fails with load JSON structure...

Comment: Or a member `std::optional<Base>`, so you can delay the construction until the whole risk of undefined behavior goes away.

Comment: @StoryTeller No, this has to be this way :( This is question about correctness of using `new` operator.

Comment: The more I read your comments and use case, the more convinced I am that deriving is the wrong thing to do.  You want to inherit a 3rd party class (which can be risky when you decide to update it; or if they don't have a virtual destructor); and you want this to handle serialization only then create a `Base load(int x)` function.  While I think what you're doing is probably safe with your example; what will you do when your static_assert fails (which it might - it's 3rd party code!)?

Comment: I'd add that any base for which that static_assert doesn't fail [can't have any virtual function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/TriviallyCopyable) which severely limits the benefits of inheritance over composition.

Comment: @UKMonkey The Base class is as simple as mine! And it can't changed very, but can use different `calulate_z` function. If I will call constructor I will be sure if 3pard library update my code would work as expected. Static assert is only to prevent my from errors. And in case that static assert fails I need to modify my code. There is second static assert that check if I use correct BaseClasses! But this out of this question and this would make this question too complicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you trying to write here? Nowhere in the link you listed does *anything like* this get suggested.

It looks like what you want is:

```
struct Base {
    int x;
    double z;

    Base(): x(0), z(0) {}
    Base(int value): x(value), z( calculate_z(x) ) {}
};

class Derived : public Base {
    std::optional<bool> force; 

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & archive)
    {
        archive( x, z, force );
    }
};

class Safer {
    Base b;
    std::optional<bool> force; 

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & archive)
    {
        archive( b.x, b.z, force );
    }
};

class Constructs {
    Base b;
    std::optional<bool> force; 

    template<class Archive>
    void load(Archive & archive)
    {
        int x, z;
        archive( x, z, force );
        b = Base( x );
        // Could be
        // b = Base( x, z );
    }

    template<class Archive>
    void save(Archive & archive)
    {
        archive( b.x, b.z/*???*/, force );
    }
};
```

Comment: No!! This would make create improper JSON :( This is more complicated. If u wanna help please help with `new` questions.

Comment: You seem very sure of that, but no-one else is. Can you give an example of *how* this is wrong? Have you *tried* this approach?

Comment: Yes. Your code will generate `{ "Unrelated": { "Base": {"x":0, "z":0}}, "force": true }`. I need `{"Derived": {"x": 0, "z":0, "fore": true}}`. There are `load_minimal` and `save_minimal` functions but this is only if class has one member.

Comment: Or are you just wanting to serialise `x` without `z`? See edit

Comment: No. I want exactly as I did in example code in my question. This is about `new` in placement not about using cereal with is very good documented. I have tried using this as a member!

Comment: You **can't** use placement `new` here safely. You no longer have a `Derived` when you do this.

Comment: @S.R `I have tried using this as a member` since by your own admission it should be a member; I would suggest you go back to it and ask a question about that not working.  I don't disagree that no one has answered your question here, but (for me) that's because not only will it not fix your problem but is likely to lead you to do some very bad practices.

Comment: Aside: Don't inherit from library classes that lack a virtual destructor. You have no way of knowing if somewhere there is a `Base * ptr = ...; delete ptr;`

Comment: You can control the naming with e.g. `cereal::make_nvp("x", b.x)`

Comment: @Caleth and on that member I can call safe `new` inplace?

Comment: Stop thinking about placement new. It doesn't help you here

Comment: So how to use Constructor in load function? I can't do sth like this `archive( b.x, b.z, force );` some fields are optional and constructor call special function if u use pass only `x`, and different if u pass `z`, and different if u pass `x` and `z`. If I would checking what is called under hood I will implement library for second time.

Comment: Why do you need `z` in the JSON if you are going to ignore it constructing a `Base`?

Comment: Fields in json are optional (mostly). Base have value, flags and time. The `Base` can be constructed just from value. Or just from flags. Or from value and flags. This is necessary, because if I set `flags` improper data will not generate event in other system. I just wanna call constructor. Even if I pass just value flags are set to special generated due to value and type. I don't wanna take implementation details, this is part for that library if I call constructor I will be sure that my apps will work correct with new version.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163328/discussion-between-s-r-and-caleth).